# JavaScript / Google Search, My url not working others are

Tags: javascript, html, google-api

I have setup a google search within a website im working on here: http://www.a-t-i-s.com/search.php

If I set the url to search anything apart from "www.a-t-i-s.com" it works fine but when its set the website url it wont work at all, the JavaScript file for the search is located here: http://a-t-i-s.com/static/js/search_script.js

As you can see its currently set to google just so I can get some results showing up.

Has anyone encountered this issue before? I found some forum threads with the same issue but no one replied to them I couldn't find anything else on this issue when searching google.

If anyone can shed light on the problem that would be awesome.

Comment: I tried it and got the same thing as you - no results, but now without doing anything it has started working.

Comment: Where did you test it? I set it back to a-t-i-s.com and its still throwing "no results" when I test searching the website on google itself it seems to work so its confusing me its as if google is rejecting it for some reason.

Comment: Ah, ok. I suspect you must have changed it when I looked at it then earlier. I'll take another look.

Comment: Many thanks, yeah I had it set to google.com just so results came up, its just confusing me because site: search on google itself works, possibly its the formatting of the results that is causing the problem but it doesn't explain why other URL's work fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this site really new in the Google index or very recently submitted? If it is it might potentially explain why you get no results back.

I can see through regular search a few URLs coming back, but I wonder if Google maybe hasn't fully indexed it 100%. I've looked at the code and the network calls and from what I can see the underlying call just doesn't return any results data, so in theory the no results response is actually correct.

This leads me to suspect your code (HTML/JS) is OK but for whatever reason Google isn't providing results.

If we cut through everything and just look at the raw underlying ajax call URL (replace YOUR_IP_ADDRESS if your real IP):

https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/web?v=1.0&q=site:www.a-t-i-s.com&userip=YOUR_IP_ADDRESS

We get this result:

```
{"responseData": {"results":[],"cursor":{"moreResultsUrl":"http://www.google.com/search?oe\u003dutf8\u0026ie\u003dutf8\u0026source\u003duds\u0026start\u003d0\u0026hl\u003den-GB\u0026q\u003dsite:www.a-t-i-s.com","searchResultTime":"0.04"}}, "responseDetails": null, "responseStatus": 200}
```

If we try another site that has hyphens in the name, just in case that might be causing a problem:

https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/web?v=1.0&q=site:ba-mro.com&userip=YOUR_IP_ADDRESS

We get results:

```
{"responseData": {"results":[{"GsearchResultClass":"GwebSearch","unescapedUrl":"http://www.ba-mro.com/","url":"http://www.ba-mro.com/","visibleUrl":"www.ba-mro.com","cacheUrl":"http://www.google.com/search?q\u003dcache:-mTL9fY7-j4J:www.ba-mro.com","title":"British Airways - Engineering - MRO","titleNoFormatting":"British Airways - Engineering - MRO","content":"British Airways Engineering Maintenance Repair and Overhaul Services - BA   MRO. British Airways Engineering has over 80 years of experience in providing \u003cb\u003e...\u003c/b\u003e"},{"GsearchResultClass":"GwebSearch","unescapedUrl":"http://www.ba-mro.com/baemro/lineMaintenance.shtml","url":"http://www.ba-mro.com/baemro/lineMaintenance.shtml","visibleUrl":"www.ba-mro.com","cacheUrl":"http://www.google.com/search?q\u003dcache:Yik3_muq8ToJ:www.ba-mro.com","title":"British Airways - Engineering - Line Maintenance","titleNoFormatting":"British Airways - Engineering - Line Maintenance","content":"British Airways Engineering Line Maintenance. We are always ready, With over   100 line maintenance stations worldwide, British Airways Engineering and its \u003cb\u003e...\u003c/b\u003e"},{"GsearchResultClass":"GwebSearch","unescapedUrl":"http://www.ba-mro.com/baemro/engStations.shtml","url":"http://www.ba-mro.com/baemro/engStations.shtml","visibleUrl":"www.ba-mro.com","cacheUrl":"http://www.google.com/search?q\u003dcache:mlII7nPYfXkJ:www.ba-mro.com","title":"British Airways - Engineering - Interactive Facilities Map","titleNoFormatting":"British Airways - Engineering - Interactive Facilities Map","content":"British Airways Engineering Interactive Facilities Map. The interactive facilities   map shows all of British Airways Engineering\u0026#39;s facilities and their capabilities \u003cb\u003e...\u003c/b\u003e"},{"GsearchResultClass":"GwebSearch","unescapedUrl":"http://www.ba-mro.com/baemro/engineeringServices.shtml","url":"http://www.ba-mro.com/baemro/engineeringServices.shtml","visibleUrl":"www.ba-mro.com","cacheUrl":"http://www.google.com/search?q\u003dcache:4amHsba6jB4J:www.ba-mro.com","title":"British Airways - Engineering - Engineering and Maintenance Services","titleNoFormatting":"British Airways - Engineering - Engineering and Maintenance Services","content":"British Airways Engineering and Maintenance Services. At British Airways we   listen to our customers and we know that every operator wants a different level of \u003cb\u003e...\u003c/b\u003e"}],"cursor":{"resultCount":"46","pages":[{"start":"0","label":1},{"start":"4","label":2},{"start":"8","label":3},{"start":"12","label":4},{"start":"16","label":5},{"start":"20","label":6},{"start":"24","label":7},{"start":"28","label":8}],"estimatedResultCount":"46","currentPageIndex":0,"moreResultsUrl":"http://www.google.com/search?oe\u003dutf8\u0026ie\u003dutf8\u0026source\u003duds\u0026start\u003d0\u0026hl\u003den-GB\u0026q\u003dsite:ba-mro.com","searchResultTime":"0.09"}}, "responseDetails": null, "responseStatus": 200}
```

You might want to post a question in the Google AJAX Search API group as this might be a bug or other problem:

https://groups.google.com/forum/?hl=en&fromgroups#!forum/Google-AJAX-Search-API

Comment: You must be some kind of sorcerer! Will ask over on the google site, many thanks for your help you are a true gent!

Comment: Ha, no sorcery! If you haven't already it is definitely worth spending a bit of time getting to know something like the Chrome inspector (Shift+Ctrl+I) or the Firefox equivalent. Select the Network option and load the page and you can see the calls being made. You'll see the ajax calls and the actual URLs that ultimately get called. Let me know how you get on - would like to know.

Comment: Yeah I use firebug but I just didn't click to look at it, so much going on in my office all reason and logic goes out of the window and is replaced by stress and insanity.